# formatted temperature measurement giving incorrect value

Tags: swift, weatherkit, measurementformatter

I am trying to show the temperature from weatherkit in a text field.
If I use 'temp.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .weather)' for -0.31C it shows a weird value of -33F.
It works for positive celsius values, only the negative ones have this issue.

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong in the code shown?
I am just starting to do some learning project with swiftUI.

```
let temp = Measurement(value: -0.31, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
print(temp)
print("Current default locale: \(Locale.current)")
print("\(temp.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .weather)))")
print(MeasurementFormatter().string(from: temp)) //this works
```

```
Output:
-0.31 °C
Current default locale: en_US (current)
-33°F
31.442°F
```

Comment: Hmmm... I get this output: `-0.31 °C  /  Current default locale: en_US (current)  /  31°F  /  31.442°F`

Comment: Same here. It works fine for me. I'm testing with a command-line app with Xcode 14.3. What version of Xcode and OS-version are you testing this on. I can't reproduce it. (Also `en_US (current)`)

Comment: Using XCode 14.0 and MacOS Ventura 13.0.1
If I try it on the 'playgrounds app' from the appstore, it works fine. But get the incorrect result inside XCode playgrounds or XCode app